# How does Next.js routing work from browser to application under the hood?

Tags: routes, control-flow, next.js13

I am trying to understand the Next.js routing fundamentally so that I can customize it according to my need. But I wasn't able to find about the workflow of the routing with a high-level explanation. I am not asking about the basic routing. I want to understand how does Next.js make connection between all structure of the application. So my questions are:

1. When a user requests a URL, what happens inside the next.js application? Inside the application from which file/folder to which file/folder it goes and what it does. What is the control flow of the Next.js before it is served to the browser
2. Is it possible to rename the index.js without using rewrites and redirect?
3. When we browser to a dynamic page like:** */post/1* **(here postId = 1), we can easily browse that page by getting the post id from the query using the useRouter hook. But is it possible to make this: ***/post?postId=1* **URL to behave like the above one as both are query parameters?
4. Beside our minified code in the .next folder, when pre-rendering pages, is Next.js add additional code?

I read the documentation and searched but wasn't able to find what I am looking for or wasn't able to understand properly. I am lacking in understanding as a beginner to this framework. Please forgive me if I made any mistake. Thanks for you help and time.